# Expiring EhCache Elements on Disk

Tags: java, caching, ehcache

Is there a way to configure Ehcache to remove entries from the disk store based on the age of the entry? I know that I can configure Ehcache to expire elements from disk when the maxElementsOnDisk property is set to something greater than zero but I want the entries to get deleted regardless of the number of entries in the disk store.